# Ubuntu Touch connecting to 3G The connection was not supported by oFono

Tags: network-manager, ubuntu-touch, 3g

I am trying to enable 3g on ubuntu touch.  I am currently on the "rogers" network in Canada and I have transferred my connection information to my phone, but when I run `nmcli con up id "rogers"` I get the following error:

> The connection was not supported by oFono

This is for a GSM network which should be supported.  I have posted my connection settings below:

```
[connection]
id=rogers
uuid=0000000000000000000000000000000 #commented out
type=gsm

[gsm]
number=*99#
username=wapuser1
password=wap
apn=internet.com
network-type=2

[ipv4]
method=auto

[serial]
baud=115200
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with the E-Plus network (simyo) in Germany. I guess this problem began in first week of July. You can still download a version from the 11th of June which works for me (http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview/raring/monthly-06/). I use CWM recovery for to flash the old images because I don't know how this works with phablet-flash.